# Select-Object throws an exception when used in a constrained session

Tags: powershell

When I configure a restricted PowerShell Session like so:

```
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Path c:\PSScripts\test.pssc `
                               -Description 'Delegation EndPoint Repro' `
                               -ExecutionPolicy Restricted `
                               -SessionType RestrictedRemoteServer `
                               -LanguageMode FullLanguage

Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Path 'c:\PSScripts\test.pssc' `
                                -Name TestSession `
                                -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI `
                                -AccessMode Remote `
                                -Force
```

Since the session is of type [RestrictiedRemoteServer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849741.aspx), I expect the Select-Object Cmdlet be available to end-users. Indeed, when users connect to this session and issue a Get-Command, Select-Object is returned as on of the available Cmdlets.
However when Select-Object is used (for example with -Last parameter), the following exception is thrown.

```
[localhost]: PS> Get-Command | Select-Object -Last 1
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Last'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Select-Object
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I ran these commands on Windows 8.1; $PSVersionTable.PSVersion = 4.0.-1.-1. Get-Command | Select-Object -Last 1 succeeded as expected. What OS/Powershell version are you using?